# Error when accessing Firebase hosted sites saying "your computer or network may be sending automated queries"

Tags: firebase

I shared a link with someone to a firebase site that I was hosting, and it worked for some time, but then all of a sudden they said they were getting the message:

> We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may be sending
>   automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request
>   right now. See Google Help for more information.

[image: Google's error page]

I was also getting it, and started checking my other firebase hosted sites and started getting the message on all of them. I didn't understand. I couldn't find a common link to understand why it was happening. So many sites linked it to a reCAPTCHA problem, but my sites don't use reCAPTCHA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link:
[GitHub forum Link](https://github.com/txthinking/brook/issues/315)

The user recommended **making sure the url started with "https"**. As soon as I typed my url with "https://" at the start, everything came up. At that point, I tried all the other URLs, and they worked too. This may be a rule for all Google-related sites.

I'm not sure if it's relevant that Chrome often trims the url in the "omnibox" or address bar, hiding the protocol, making it easy to miss when copying/pasting? E.g. :

[image: trimmed url in address bar]

Note, I tried accessing these pages without https (by typing "http://") but my browser now seemed to correct it and force it to be "https://", so I couldn't replicate the problem again.

I don't know exactly why it started, but I know that I wish I found this information sooner, because it was very frustrating, and the info out there wasn't helpful, except for the link I posted above. So hopefully, when someone like me searches for "firebase" and the error text "your computer or network may be sending automated queries", they might see this and possibly be saved a headache.